# How put comment from json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want the screen to display a list of reservations. The full list is in .json file. The reservation choose by entering shortened names airport. The problem is that we displays the names of the entries, but we are not showing full the name of the airport?

my reservations.html

```
<h3>Reserve for flight</h3>

<div class="controls controls-row">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Origin" ng-model="reserve.origin">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Destination" ng-model="reserve.destination">
</div>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reserveFlight()">Reserve</a>

<h3>Your Reservations</h3>

<table ng-show="reservations.length" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Origin</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="flight in reservations">
      <td>{{flight.number}}</td>
      <td>
        <a ng-href="#/airports/{{flight.origin}}">
          {{flight.origin + ' - ' + flight.originFullName}}
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a ng-href="#/airports/{{flight.destination}}">
          {{flight.destination + ' - ' + flight.destinationFullName}}
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div ng-hide="reservations.length" class="alert alert-info">
  You don't currently have any reservations, why not make one now?
</div>
```

my app.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('airline', ['ngRoute'])

  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/destinations.html',
      controller: 'destinationsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/airports/:airportCode', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/airport.html',
      controller: 'airportCtrl'
    })
    .when('/flights', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/flights.html',
      controller: 'flightsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/reservations', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/reservations.html',
      controller: 'reservationsCtrl'
    })
}])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.airportTemplate = 'partials/airport.html';

  $scope.setActive = function (type){
    $scope.destinationsActive = '';
    $scope.flightsActive = '';
    $scope.reservationsActive = '';

    $scope[type + 'Active'] = 'active';
  }
})

.controller('destinationsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.setActive('destinations');

  $scope.sidebarURL = 'partials/airport.html'
  $scope.formURL = 'partials/form.html'

  $scope.currentAirport = null;

  $scope.setAirport = function(code){
    $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports[code];
  };

  $scope.editAirport = function(code){
    $scope.editing = $scope.airports[code];
  };

  $http.get('data/airports.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.airports = response.data;
  });

}])

.controller('flightsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
  $http.get('data/flights.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.flights = response.data;
});
  $scope.setActive('flights');
  $scope.airports = {};
}])

.controller('airportCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
  $http.get('data/airports.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.airports = response.data;
    $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports[$routeParams.airportCode];
  });
}])

.controller('reservationsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
  $http.get('data/flights.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.reservations = response.data;
    $scope.reservations = [];
    $scope.reserve = {origin: "", destination: ""};

    $scope.reserveFlight = function(){
        console.log($scope.reserve);
        $scope.reservations.push($scope.reserve);

    }
  });

  $scope.setActive('reservations');

}])
```

flights.json file

```
{
    "number": 112,
    "origin": "ATL",
    "destination": "LAX",
    "price": 232,
    "originFullName": "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International Airport",
    "destinationFullName": "Los Angeles International Airport"
},
{
    "number": 812,
    "origin": "ATL",
    "destination": "JFK",
    "price": 192,
    "originFullName": "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International Airport",
    "destinationFullName": "John F. Kennedy International Airport"
}, ...
```

This we now showing 
[image]

and it should look like this 
[image]

Comment: For the record, I am really really confused about the title. It got totally and utterly nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the JSON, you override the data with empty array, losing it all:

```
$http.get('data/flights.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.reservations = response.data;
    $scope.reservations = [];
```

I have no idea why you're doing it, but naturally it cause that you won't have anything in the array. It will be empty.

So you will see only reservations you add by clicking the button. However, you don't have the "originFullName" and "destinationFullName" in the object you're adding, only the short names.

I can't fix your code since the very base logic is wrong. You can either add two more textboxes for the full names, or not clear the array, and you'll see the existing data. (But still see partial when adding new items.)